# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string

Tags: nodejs, bcryptjs

Buenas me esta enviando un error en esta parte de codigo dice que el error es en linea 29 y la cual corresponde a usuario.password = await bcryptjs.hash(password, salt);

Detallo el codigo en el sisguiente lineas de codigo
Como puedo solucionalrlo??

```javascript
const usuariosPost = async (req = request, res = response) => {
    const { nombre, correo, password } = req.body;
    const usuario = new Usuario({ nombre, correo, password });

    const salt = await bcryptjs.genSalt();
    usuario.password = await bcryptjs.hash(password, salt);

    await usuario.save();

    res.json({
        usuario
    })
}
```

Y me aparece este error

```
(node:11616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
    at _async (C:\Users\kenda\Desktop\Restapi\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:214:46)
    at C:\Users\kenda\Desktop\Restapi\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:223:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.bcrypt.hash (C:\Users\kenda\Desktop\Restapi\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:222:20)
    at usuariosPost (C:\Users\kenda\Desktop\Restapi\controllers\usuarios.js:29:39)
(node:11616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11616) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: en su:  bcryptjs.hash(password, salt) por bcryptjs.hash(password.toString(), salt).

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo no usar async/await en este caso, ya que bcrypt tiene una funcion de callback no bloqueante, que te va a permitir hacer todo directamente, incluido el salt, y guardar el usuario despues.

te propongo cambiar esto:

```
const salt = await bcryptjs.genSalt();
usuario.password = await bcryptjs.hash(password, salt);

await usuario.save();

res.json({
    usuario
})
```

por esto:

```
bcrypt.hash(password, 15, (err, hash)=>{  //donde '15' son las rondas de cifrado haciendo salt automaticamente, como indican en su documentacion. 
  usuario.password = hash;
  usuario.save(); //no necesitas esperar a que el usuario se guarde para enviar la respuesta
                 //a no ser que quieras comprobar que se ha guardado correctamente
  res.json({
   usuario
  })
})
```

espero te ayude mi respuesta,

saludos.